# How dose one correctly migrate a working Post Request from VS c# to VS Xamarin c#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, http-post, cross-platform

How dose one correctly migrate a working Post Request from VS c# to VS Xamarin c#, without it going bonkers or give me "Waiting for Activation" messages.

Please, I can use any help I can get. I learn best while hands on and seeing examples related to that witch i'm working with. Also a reason why I have trouble following most of the examples here. Right now the code is only giving me back a string with Id = 10, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}".

First off, I made a prototype of a program that I wanted to migrate into Xamarin later. The reason being, that at the time, I didn't have the resources to jump right into Xamarin.

Now I have the resources, but it seems i'm still lacking in understanding the Framework of Xamarin. This is my first project in Xamarin and I have never worked with it before. Furtionaly, my problem only leis right now with the Post Request in Xamarin. It is not like I haven't spent time researching and i'm still Learning. But I still haven't quite understood the setting up the Post request with its HttpRequestMessages.content or that of HttpClient. Hier first the origgenal VS c# verssion, to show the solution i have in VS c#.

```
public string SendAndRecive(byte[] postData, string endPoint)
    {
        string strResponseValue = string.Empty;

        // Sending the request
        // Knocking on the door
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Declaring the packaged
        request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

        // Handing over the package
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);

        } // end of StreamWrite

        // Asking for receipt
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {

            // Checking status
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("error code:  " + response.StatusCode.ToString() + response.ToString());

            } // end of if

            // Reciving and catching data
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    } // end of StreamReader
                } // end of if
            } // end of responseStream
        } // end of response

        return strResponseValue;

    } // end of send and recive
```

This is what I have made it into while trying to follow several examples, step by step. While taking the original apart, step by step. I even taken in the coding of the content into the Method, instead of coding it beforehand, because i wasn't sure how to set up the HttpRequestMessage.Content.

```
 public async Task<dynamic> SendAndReciveAsync(string PostData, string EndPoint)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(EndPoint);
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;

        byte[] Data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PostData);
        ByteArrayContent Content = new ByteArrayContent(Data, 0, Data.Length);

        request.Content = Content;

        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        }
        string recivedContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(recivedContent));
    }
```

Thank You for your trouble and time, first fir reading this far and secound for any help you may give. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned any exception or compile errors. I would simplify your SendAndReciveAsync method to something like that:

```
public async Task<T> SendAndReciveAsync<T>(string postData, string endpoint)
{
    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        var content = new System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent(data);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        content.Headers.ContentLength = data.Length;

        var response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var recivedContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(recivedContent));
     }
}
```

This should work. To exactly port your WebRequest to HttpClient you could use StreamContent instead of ByteArraContent too. But then postData has to be a stream.